# htaccess 301 redirect to disable deleting question/post

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to block deleting posts for the users by using htaccess redirect. When the user clicks on the delete button the following url is `https://website.com/?ptype=preview&delete=1&qid=66` (after `&delete` part `=1&qid=66` changes depending on the  question(post) id.)

i want to redirect `https://website.com/?ptype=preview&delete=*(all posts)` to for example `https://website.com/` or `https://website.com/abc`

Can anyone help me about that ?

Answer (score 2):

Any particular reason you want to use .htaccess rules instead of modifying [Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) or utilizing the [`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/) hook, or better yet the [`before_delete_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/before_delete_post/) hook?

If for some reason you're set on using the .htaccess file, you'll need to check the `%{QUERY_STRING}` for the `delete=1`. Something like this should get you started:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)delete=1($|&)
RewriteRule . https://website.com/abc [L,R=301,NC]
```

Again, I'd argue that using 301s in .htaccess is like using a screwdriver to kill a fly. Does it work? Certainly - though there's probably a better tool for it. Using the [`before_delete_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/before_delete_post/) hook would provide you with the most extensible, secure, and easy-to-maintain options.